# What kind of functions cannot be used in the critical section of the spin lock?

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency, linux-kernel, spinlock

I'm kind of confused about what sort of functions are not allowed in a spin lock's critical section.

In particular I'm confused about reentrant functions. I thought that all reentrant functions are unsafe to use in a spin lock's critical section, but it appears that functions like kfree and memcpy are ok to use.

So how do we know what functions are ok or not ok? I generally think anything that might block is unsafe, but don't all reentrant functions have the capacity/potential to block?

Also what is the role and relationship of the interrupt handler to spin locks?

Comment: You're mixing things up: reentrant =/= can sleep.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli So is the only restriction on what you can do inside a spin lock is to not sleep?

Comment: Yeah, that's basically it. You must be careful not to call any function that has some possibility to sleep.

Answer (score 0):

You have reentrant backward: Re-entrant functions are the functions that are safe to use while a spinlock is held.

Many non-reentrant functions can be ok as well.

The primary concern is calling a function that directly or indirectly tries to acquire the same lock you're currently holding which leads to deadlock.

---

Specific to `kmalloc`, though you did not specify this in your question:

The general answer above is the reason why you've heard `kmalloc` may not be safe to use within a spinlock: It also acquires a spinlock by default. Use the flag `GFP_ATOMIC` to control whether `kmalloc` attempts to acquire a spinlock:

> GFP_ATOMIC     The allocation is high priority and must not sleep. This
> is the flag to use in interrupt handlers, in bottom halves, while
> holding a spinlock, and in other situations where you cannot sleep.
>
> http://books.gigatux.nl/mirror/kerneldevelopment/0672327201/ch11lev1sec4.html

Comment: Malloc is reentrant and it's not safe to use while a spin lock is being held, so I don't think this is true

Comment: @Shisui Where did you head that from?

Comment: Do you mean `kmalloc`? Is your question focused on the Linux kernel or not? `kmalloc` has a `get_free_pages`-style bitmask argument which determines what sort of reentrancy requirements it meets. E.g. it is more reentrant with `GFP_ATOMIC`.

Comment: @Kaz yes, kmalloc.

Comment: @Shisui I've updated the answer with information relevant to your `kmalloc` concerns.